# Canvas specification confusion when retrieving image from the 2d drawingContext

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have some confusion in my mind as to how the of Canvas API is defined. Canvas is covered in 2 - parts:

1. HTML Canvas 2D Context Specification(https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/) and

   HTML5 Canvas Element specification(https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/the-canvas-element.html):

Here is what the Canvas2d spec says how a UserAgent should draw an image.

> Render the shape or image onto an infinite transparent black bitmap, creating image A, as described in the previous sections. For shapes, the current fill, stroke, and line styles must be honored, and the stroke must itself also be subjected to the current transformation matrix.

**In the canvas element:**

> The **toDataURL()** function returns the contents of the Canvas and I cannot specify the origin and height and width of the rectangle for capturing the image from the canvas.

**In CanvasRenderingContext2D**:

> The **getImageData()** function return an ImageData object representing the underlying pixel data for the area of the canvas denoted by the rectangle whose corners are the four points (sx, sy), (sx+sw, sy), (sx+sw, sy+sh), (sx, sy+sh), in canvas coordinate space units. Pixels outside the canvas must be returned as transparent black.

To zoom In, **I copy the image onto a much larger offscreen canvas** so as not to lose the zoomed-in image and later use the same to let the user zoom out. The is frustrating because the operations had to be performed on both onscreen and offscreen canvases because of the inability to specify the width and height of the drawing context. Is there a API that I am missing in the Canvas??

**Note:**
*I created an editor that performs pretty much all the operations that you can in Paint and the operations can be performed on zoomed in or zoomed out images as well. Hence I use these API.*

Comment: Zooming shouldn't require the use of `toDataURL()` nor `getImageData()`. It can be done with `ctx.drawImage` alone.

Comment: I created an editor that performs pretty much all the operations that you can in Paint and the operations can be performed on zoomed in or zoomed out images as well. Hence I use this API.

Comment: that doesn't change the fact that for copying a canvas to an other, you should use `drawImage` instead of `toDataURL` or `getImageData`+ `putImageData`. Even better : keep track of all your drawings operations and redraw everything on the resized canvas (you'll avoid resizing issues in zoomed-in canvas)

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems you are quite far along in development. But as @Kaiido says, refactor your code to zoom using the much (much!) more efficient `drawImage` with a large original image or alternatively, replay your scene drawing commands after setting `.scale`. As you have probably seen in the docs, `drawImage` also has scaling & clipping overrides. Yes, *`toDataURL` only exports the entire visible canvas* content. And *`getImageData` is not meant for block operations like zooming* -- it's meant for pixel manipulation.

Comment: I could be very wrong, but I suspect you're seeing *viewport* and the image data as the same thing. You have to separate the two - think of it as two layers, viewport being a virtual binocular which is what you see on the screen. You can perform zoom in/out on the viewport to see details more close-up temporary without affecting the actual image data (see transformation matrix) meaning you don't have to do copy operations all the time. It's only when you change the actual size of the image data/bitmap or parts of it (regardless of viewport) you would have to change the image bitmap.